# Clustered index trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

In our production system (SQL Server 2008 / R2) there is a table in which generated documents are stored.

The documents have a reference (`varchar`) and a sequence_nr (`int`). The document may be generated multiple times and each iteration gets saved in this table incrementing the sequence number. Additionally each record has a data column (`varbinary`) and a timestamp as well as a user tag.

The only reason to query this table is for auditing purposes later on and during inserts.

The primary key for the table is clustered over the `reference` and `sequence_nr` columns.

As you can probably guess generation of documents and thus the data in the table (since a document can be generated again at a later time) does not grow in order.

I realized this after inserts in the table started timing out.

The inserts are performed with a stored procedure. The stored procedure determines the current max `sequence_nr` for the given reference and inserts the new row with the next `sequence_nr`.

I am fairly sure a poor choice of clustered index is causing the timeout problems, since records will be inserted for already existing references, only with a different sequence_nr and thus may end up anywhere in the record collection, but most likely not at the end.

On to my question: would it be better to go for a non-clustered index as primary key or would it be better to introduce an identity column, make it a clustered primary key and keep an index for the combination of reference and `sequence_nr`?

Knowing that for the time being (and not at all as far as we can foresee) there is no need to query this table intensively, except for the case where a new `sequence_nr` must be determined.

Edit in answer to questions:
Tbh, I'm not sure about the timeout in the production environment. I do know that new documents get added in parallel running processes.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_document] (
    [reference]     VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    [sequence_nr]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [creation_date] DATETIME2      NOT NULL,
    [creation_user] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [document_data] VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

Primary Key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_document]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([reference] ASC, [sequence_nr] ASC) 
    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_save_document] @reference     NVARCHAR (50),
                                           @sequence_nr   INT OUTPUT,
                                           @creation_date DATETIME2,
                                           @creation_user NVARCHAR(50),
                                           @document_data VARBINARY(max)
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @current_sequence_nr INT

      SELECT @current_sequence_nr = max(sequence_nr)
      FROM   [dbo].[tbl_document]
      WHERE  [reference] = @reference

      IF @current_sequence_nr IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @sequence_nr = 1
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @sequence_nr = @current_sequence_nr + 1
        END

      INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_document]
                  ([reference],
                   [sequence_nr],
                   [creation_date],
                   [creation_user],
                   [document_data])
      VALUES      (@reference,
                   @sequence_nr,
                   @creation_date,
                   @creation_user,
                   @document_data)
  END
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is your timeout set to? 30 seconds? I'm not sure even the most rampant page splitting could cause that. What is the code in the procedure and the table definition?

Comment: Hi Martin, I've added the table/key and procedure definition. They're currently dealing with about 130K records, which does seem absurdly low for timeouts, I'll admit that.

Comment: The `@reference` parameter is `NVARCHAR (50)` but the column datatype is `VARCHAR(50)` this will prevent index use when looking up `@current_sequence_nr`. What isolation level are you running at as well?

Comment: Hmm hadn't even noticed the difference in type. Thought it was a typo at first, but it's actually in the database project like that. Will fix that asap. Transaction isolationlevel is ReadCommitted.

Comment: BTW: At read committed you can get PK violations with that code if concurrent inserts both try and insert a document for the same  reference at the same time.

Comment: I had realised that. However, the batch that generates documents (using concurrent worker processes) can never generate multiple iterations of a given document in 1 run. It seemed sufficiently safe at the time :/

Comment: Well in that case fixing the datatype issue may well be enough then. It should then be able to do an index seek rather than an index scan. Perhaps the reason for the timeouts is that currently your process is getting blocked by concurrent data modifications on rows that it doesn't even need to be reading.

Comment: Thanx for your input, I'll dive into it. 
Would you advise switching to a non-clustered index for the given scenario or keep it as is and work with the modified stored procedure first?

Comment: It's quite wide for a clustered index key but as it seems you haven't got any non clustered indexes it might be fine as is. Without knowing the queries that run against the table it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a clustered index physically reorders the records of the table to match the index order, it is only useful if you want to read out several consecutive records in that order because then the whole records can be read by doing a sequential read on the disk.

If you are only using data that is present in the index, there is no gain in make it clustered, because the index in itself (clustered or not) is kept separate from the data and in order.

So for your specific case a non-clustered index is the right way to go. Inserts won't need to reorder the data (only the index) and finding a new `sequence_nr` can be fulfill by looking at the index alone.

Comment: Marked your answer, since it's a useful answer on it's own. After Martin Smith's help I don't know if I actually wil be applyting it anytime soon, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the setting the `PK` `not clustered`, since:

- keeping a b-tree balanced when the key has `varchar` makes the each leaf much bigger.
- you for what you say, you aren't scanning this table for many rows at a time